# Calling AWK and Shell Scripting

Tags: shell

I'm having a problem with a Shell Script.

In a nutshell I want to print the "$2" column of the file "$1" in my script "showColumn"

So, what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{print $($2)}' $1
exit 0
```

Ok, I know that $($2) is totally incorrect, but you can see what I'm trying to do.

So what I want when I write "./showColumn file.txt 2" is printing the second column of file.txt but I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: You can use: `awk -v n=$2 '{print $n}' "$1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v column="$2" '{print $column}' "$1"
exit 0
```

Comment: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)